# read tzdata files with java

Tags: java, timezone

I want to read the tzdata files (TimeZone) to convert a sourcetime in a targettime. I have downloaded the tzdata files, has anybody an example for me to read the tzdata file out?

Answer (score 2):

Might want to check out JodaTime. Not only does this use the tzdata files, I seem to recall he had an importer for them for his libraries

Comment: I want to read out the tzdata fles because, i want to save it on my mobile in an android app and later i will update the app. So i dont find an other solution for using the actual tzdata files in android.

Answer (score 0):

Java API contains a TimeZone class that gives you access to the TZ's defined on the host. So no need to read the tzdata file. Later you may use TimeZone in Calendar.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html